# Class instance variable is reduced when popping a different list in Python

Tags: python, list, oop

I am attempting the Probability Calculator from freecodecamp, which can be found [Here](https://repl.it/github/freeCodeCamp/boilerplate-probability-calculator)

In a class function to randomly select n items from a list, I access the contents of my list via `self.contents`, which is an instance variable for whatever hat filled with balls I make. My function looks as such:

```
def draw(self,num_balls_drawn):
  randomlist = []
  templist = self.contents
  if num_balls_drawn <= len(templist):
    for x in range(num_balls_drawn):
      popped = templist.pop(random.randint(0, len(templist)-1)) # random has been imported
      randomlist.append(popped)
    return randomlist 

  else:
    return self.contents #If you ask for more items than there are in list, just returns list
```

Therefore, when I create a class instance using this code:

```
class Hat:
  def __init__(self,**kwargs):
    self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
    contents=[]
    for key in self.__dict__:
      for x in range(self.__dict__.get(key)):
        contents.append(key)
    self.contents= contents
```

And then create an instance with `hat = Hat(blue=4, red=2, green=6)`, then testing my functions with`print(hat.contents) print(hat.draw(7)) print(hat.contents) print(hat.draw(7))`

I would hope to be given a list of `['blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'red', 'red', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green']` for `hat.contents` and a list such as `['blue', 'blue', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'blue', 'green']` for `hat.draw(7)`

However, on the second attempt of using these statements, I instead am returned `['blue', 'blue', 'green', 'green', 'green']` and
`['blue', 'blue', 'green', 'green', 'green']`

Both of which are somehow a length of only 5.

It seems despite setting up a temporary list `templist`,  my `self.contents` is still shortened everytime I pop an item out of `templist`.

If anyone could offer a solution to my Issue that would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please create a [mcve]? Provide the result you expect and something that we can run and get the wrong result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that self.contents is passed by address and not by value. What you could do is change `templist = self.contents` to `templist = self.contents[:]`. The new draw function would be as follows:

```
def draw(self,num_balls_drawn):
  randomlist = []
  templist = self.contents[:]
  if num_balls_drawn <= len(templist):
    for x in range(num_balls_drawn):
      popped = templist.pop(random.randint(0, len(templist)-1)) # random has been imported
      randomlist.append(popped)
    return randomlist 

  else:
    return self.contents #If you ask for more items than there are in list, just returns list
```

Comment: what should I research to learn more about why what you changed works? Thanks

Comment: @FredB look for passing by value and by reference, I believe it's easier to learn it in C or C++ than in Python, here's a small explanation that can help you understand it better [Pass by reference vs value in Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pass-by-reference-vs-value-in-python/). What you should know, is that you should be careful assigning list, always try to copy/deepcopy the list depending on how you want your code to behave. To understand those concepts please refer to the following link: [Shallow vs Deep Copying of Python Objects](https://realpython.com/copying-python-objects/)